# create sub-domain without express

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to run express app and fortunejs api side by side, to do this, I tried to use forever and forever-monitor.

server.js file:

```
var forever = require('forever-monitor'); 
var child = new (forever.Monitor)('app.js'); //express
var child = new (forever.Monitor)('api.js'); //fortune

child.on('watch:restart', function(info){
      console.error('Restaring script because ' + info.file + ' changed');
});

child.on('exit', function () {
    console.log('your-filename.js has exited after 3 restarts');
});

child.start();
```

I understand the problem can occur because both scripts are competing for the same spot, so I guess my question is how do I run api script as a sub-domain, ...

Many Thanks for looking into my problem,

## Update, following Emil's answer

api.js

```
var express = require('express'),
http = require('http'),
path = require('path'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
config = require('./config/config.json'),
db = require('./models/connect');
console.log('\033[2J');
app = express();

var publicUser = require('./routes/publicUser'),
storeUser = require('./routes/storeUser'),
api = require('./routes/fortune'),
adminUser = require('./routes/adminUser');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use('/', publicUser);
app.use('/store', storeUser);
app.use('/admin', adminUser);
app.use('/api', api);


//Load Server
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.listen(config.port, function(){

    console.log('listening to port ' + config.port);

});
```

## fortune.js route

```
var fortune = require('fortune');
var express = fortune.express;
var app = express.Router();
var config = require('../config/config.json');

    app = fortune({
        adapter:config.conn.adapter,
        db:config.conn.db,
        host:config.conn.host,
        port:config.conn.port,
        username:config.conn.username,
        password:config.conn.password,
        baseUrl:config.conn.baseUrl
    });

    app.resource('jobs', {
        job: String,
        title: String,
        info: String
    });
    app.resource('user', {

        user: String,
        pass: String    
    }); 

module.exports = app;
```

## error

```
Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object     
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ash/www/app.js:21:6)
```

Comment: also all my 'A' Records are pointing to the same ip

Answer (score 2):

If you truly want to run multiple nodejs servers to support this setup, you need to run them on different ports. One could be hosted on localhost:81 and the other on localhost:82. To get them to play nice on the same port you need a reverse proxy in front. This is often set up with **nginx**.

Another approach is to make the two applications run on the same **http** server. Looking over the **fortunejs** documentation I've found that it use express and it presents it through:

> Fortune.router property
>
> Namespace for the router, which is actually an instance of express.

[Fortune.js docs](http://fortunejs.com/docs/)

It should be possible just to start fortunejs and use its router property to add your own api methods:

```
var fortune = require('fortune');
var options = {
  db: 'demo_app'
};
var app = fortune(options);
app.router.get('/your-own-route', function(req,res) {
  res.send("this is awesome!");
});
```

Comment: is that mean I can comment out app=express();?

Comment: Yep, and switch it out with app from fortune. If you split your fontune app and the other api into two, then export the fortune app and require it from the other place.

Comment: dont know, im getting an error on the first line that is trying to use express,  app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

Comment: Oh did not see you added the code to the question. You should set the last app to be app = app.router. Or refactor to make it more explicit: fortuneApp = fortune(...; expressApp = fortuneApp.router;

Comment: if i change it to fortuneApp = fortune, what happens to app.set? how is app.listen work ? i really wish i could run it as a separate route

Comment: app.set should still work, at least if it does not conflict with fortune's use of express. One way run each app separately is to indeed start them both, but still in the same script. This will still start them on two ports, so to handle this you need a proxy, like this: https://gist.github.com/davemo/4027855